# como hago que sweetAlert funcione si abro mi proyecto desde github pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, sweetalert

cuando abro mi proyecto(juego del ahorcado) desde github pages no funciona bien como me funciona en mi computadora y me saltan muchos errores relacionados a sweetAlert
como hago que funcione?
[image: esos son los errores que me lanza]

ademas no importa si el usuario gana o pierda el programa sigue funcionando y no se corta ni tira la alerta con sweetAlert

Comment: ¿Leíste bien el segundo mensaje de error? Parece que tratas de cargar el script con el protocolo `http://` y debes cambiarlo a `https://`. Con eso debe resolverse el problema.

Comment: Cuando dices "desde mi maquina" a que te refieres, solo estas dando doble clic al archivo HTML o lo montaste en un servidor local? , porque las rutas absolutas estan apuntando al sitio github.io no a "tu maquina"

Comment: cuando abro el proyecto desde mi escritorio no me salen esos errores pero cuando lo hago desde github pages si

Comment: estoy usando sweetAlert usando <script src="sweetAlert.js"></script>

Comment: hay alguna otra forma de usarlo ?

Comment: [Aqui está lo que necesitas para que te podamos ayudar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)